# Uniform lower bound for the distance between terms of a linear recurrence sequence

Tags: nt.number-theory, recurrences, difference-equations

Let $(u_k)_{k=0}^\infty$ be a non-degenerate linear recurrence sequence of algebraic numbers. Denote by $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m$ its characteristic roots, and suppose that $\alpha := \underset{i}{\max}\{\lvert\alpha_i\rvert\} > 1$.
It was proved by Evertse and by Van der Poorten and Schlickwei that for every such sequence:

- There exist only finitely many pairs $n,k$ with $n\neq k$ such that
  $u_n = u_k$.
- For every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $K$ such that for every $k \ge K$,
  $ \lvert u_k \rvert > \alpha^{(1-\varepsilon)k} $.

(See [Evertse's paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1984__53_2_225_0.pdf), page 5 and Corollary 4.)

These results got me thinking about the following problem. For every $K$ define
$$ d_K = \inf\{\lvert u_n - u_k \rvert:n,k\ge K,\: n\neq k \},$$
and $d = \lim d_K$.
My question is whether $d>0$.

Fixing some $l>0$, $(u_{k+l} - u_k)_{k=0}^\infty$ is also a linear recurrence sequence with the same characteristic roots, and thus $\lvert u_{k+l} - u_k \rvert \underset{k\to\infty}{\to}\infty$. The problem is of course, that the convergence might not be uniform in $l$.